# Is $(X,\mathcal T)$ necessarily an indiscrete space?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be an infinite set with $\mathcal T$ a topology on $X$. If $X$ is the only infinite subset of $X$ that is open, is $(X,\mathcal T)$ necessarily an indiscrete space?

My intuitive thinking leads me to think that the answer is NO. We know that, if it is the indiscrete space, then $\mathcal T = \{ \emptyset, X \}$. Notice, however, that we are only given tat $X$ is the only INFINITE subset of $\mathcal T$, we have no information regarding the other possible finite open sets of $X$, that is, there may exist a finite subset $A \subset X$ with $A \in \mathcal T$. This is surely not the indiscrete space, yet it still satisfies the criteria given in the question.

Is there a better exact example that I can provide that might help show my point in a more rigorous mathematical way?

Comment: The usual terminology is the anti-discrete topology, or the coarse topology. The fine topology is a synonym for the  (more commonly used) discrete topology. I suppose the word "indiscrete" has too many non-mathematical nuances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea, but in order to make it convincing, you have to produce an actual counterexample. Here’s a simple one: let $X=\Bbb N$, and let $\tau=\big\{\varnothing,\{0\},\Bbb N\}$. It’s straightforward to verify that $\tau$ really is a topology on $X$, and that $X$ is the only infinite open subset of $X$.

With a little more work you can make the space $T_0$. Once again let $X=\Bbb N$, for each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $U_n=\{k\in\Bbb N:k<n\}$, and let $\tau=\{\Bbb N\}\cup\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$.

You cannot make the space $T_1$, however: if $X$ is $T_1$, and $x\in X$, then $X\setminus\{x\}$ is open.